# Retirar os excessos de espaços em branco de uma string

Tags: c++, string

Preciso fazer um programa que leia um arquivo de texto, copie as informações e repasse para outro arquivo, mas sem as linhas em branco, sem comentarios de codigo (que inicia em "//") e remover excesso de espaços em branco entre palavras.
A funcao le_limpa_e_salva faz seu trabalho, mas a funcao limpa_espacos esta retornando strings vazias, e por isso, ta criando arquivo novo vazio. E eu nao sei pq ta fazendo isso. alguem ajuda por favor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void limpa_espacos(string &str)
{
    int p1= 0; // ponteiro para string de entrada
    int p2= 0; // para string de saida
    string temp; // guarda a string a medida que é limpa
    
    while(str[p1]!='\0') // varre a string ate o fim
    {
        temp[p2]= str[p1]; // copia uma posicao da string de entrada para temp
        
        if(str[p1]==' ') // se essa posicao é um espaco
        {
            while(str[p1+1]!='\0' && str[p1+1]==' ') // enquanto nao chegar no fim da string e as 
                                                     // proximas posicoes continuam sendo espacos
            {
                p1++; // vai empurrando o ponteiro da string de entrada
            }
        }
        
        // senão, apenas incrementa ambos os ponteiros, ou incrementa de qualquer forma
        p1++;
        p2++;
    }
    
    temp[p2]= '\0'; // fecha a string
    str= temp;
}

void le_limpa_e_salva (ifstream &lod, ofstream &sav, string st)
{
    // enquanto tiver uma linha no arquivo com caracteres, esse "while" vai rodar
    while (getline(lod, st)) // faz leitura de uma linha do arquivo
    {
        if(!st.empty() && (st[0] != '/' && st[1] != '/')) // se a linha nao estiver vazia
        {
            cout << "\nantes de limpar espacos: " << st << "\n";
            limpa_espacos(st);
            cout << "\ndepois de limpar espacos: " << st << "\n";
            sav << st << "\n"; // grava essa linha no novo arquivo e pula para linha de baixo       
        }               
    }           
    lod.close();
    sav.close();        
    cout << "\n\nArquivo copiado com sucesso!\n\n";
}

int main()
{
    ifstream load;
    ofstream save;
    string str, apaga;
    
    // arq_orig: guarda o nome do arquivo digitado pelo usuario (arquivo fonte)
    // arq_dest: guarda o nome do arquivo digitado pelo usuario (arquivo de destino)
    char arq_orig[1023], arq_dest[1023]; 

    cout << "Digite o nome do arquivo a ser copiado, com sua extensao.\n";
    cout << "Digite: ";

    // muito melhor que colocar no codigo, o local do arquivo a ser lido
    // e o local do novo arquivo a ser criado, pois para cada execucao
    // em computador diferente, esse trecho do codigo deveria ser alterado.
    // Alem disso, ha diferenca de formatacao desse caminho para Windows e Linux.
    
    gets(arq_orig); // "pega" o nome digitado pelo usuario

    load.open(arq_orig); // lê o arquivo com esse nome

    if(load) // verificacao de erro
    {
        cout << "Digite o nome do arquivo que recebera o texto copiado, com sua extensao.\n";
        cout << "Digite: ";
        
        gets(arq_dest);
    
        save.open(arq_dest);
    
        if (save)
        {
            le_limpa_e_salva (load, save, str);
        
            load.close();
            save.close();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\n\nFalha ao criar arquivo de destino! Fechando programa.\n\n";
        }                           
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\n\nFalha ao abrir arquivo fonte! Fechando programa.\n\n";
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Problema resolvido.

Answer (score 0):

Olá!

Você escreveu algo como C e não C++. Para copiar os valores para a string de saída use `'+'` que é redefinido para strings e faz o que você quer.

```
       temp[p2]= str[p1]; // C, mas temp deve ter sido alocado antes
```

Em C já deveria haver memória alocada para a nova string e aí se pode copiar. Em C++ use

```
       temp += str[p1]; // C++, aloca conforme preciso
```

Mas considere essa função

```
string      trim(string& str)
{
    string nova{};
    char* p = &str[0];
    char branco = 0;
    while( *p!=0)
    {
        if ( *p == ' ')
            if ( branco == 0 )
            {
                branco = 1;
                nova += *p;
            }
            else
                ;
        else
        {
            branco = 0;
            nova += *p;
        }
        p++;
    };  // while()
    return nova;   
}
```

que faz o que você quer e é mais flexível porque retorna uma string e pode usar em uma expressão como

```
    const string teste[] =
    { 
        "  teste    t e s    te  ",
        "azul",
        "  azul",
        "azul  ",
        " azul",
        "azul "
    };

    for ( auto str : teste )
        std::cout << "\nAntes: '" << str <<
            "' Depois: '" << trim(str) << "'\n";
```

#### saida

```
PS C:\src\CPP\flt> g++ -o tst -Wall -std=c++17 tle.cpp
PS C:\src\CPP\flt> ./tst

Antes: '  teste    t e s    te  ' Depois: ' teste t e s te '

Antes: 'azul' Depois: 'azul'

Antes: '  azul' Depois: ' azul'

Antes: 'azul  ' Depois: 'azul '

Antes: ' azul' Depois: ' azul'

Antes: 'azul ' Depois: 'azul '
PS C:\src\CPP\flt>
```

#### deste exemplo

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string      trim(string& str);

int main(void)
{
    const string teste[] =
    { 
        "  teste    t e s    te  ",
        "azul",
        "  azul",
        "azul  ",
        " azul",
        "azul "
    };

    for ( auto str : teste )
        std::cout << "\nAntes: '" << str <<
            "' Depois: '" << trim(str) << "'\n";

    return 0;   
}


string      trim(string& str)
{
    string nova{};
    char* p = &str[0];
    char branco = 0;
    while( *p!=0)
    {
        if ( *p == ' ')
            if ( branco == 0 )
            {
                branco = 1;
                nova += *p;
            }
            else
                ;
        else
        {
            branco = 0;
            nova += *p;
        }
        p++;
    };  // while()
    return nova;   
}
// main.cpp
```

### Alternativa: use uma máquina de estados

Como seu programa é um filtro e passa uma vez só pela entrada, uma máquina de estados é algo muito mais simples. E leia o arquivo como uma sequência de letras. Eis os estados:

- lendo um valor
- depois de ler um espaço
- depois de ler uma /
- depois de ler um espaço adicional
- depois de ler um segunda /
- ler um `\n`
- fim de arquivo

Não precisa de funções para nada se usar isso. Se precisar escreva e mostro um exemplo